# R Shiny HTML object is rendered on every tabPanel()

Tags: r, d3.js, shiny

I am trying to create a shiny app where users can upload their own data and get a visualization of the network dynamics in their data. I'm using the `render.d3movie()` function from the `ndtv` package to create an HTML object from the network with some user input parameters. I want to display this HTML object in one of my `tabPanel()`s but weirdly, it shows up on *every* panel instead. I tried with a different HTML file and this one works just fine. To reproduce this, you'll need to download the [test](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TrNugaTgBLC454NfTKkypZxR4w1vy_i_/view?usp=sharing) and [network animation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1844SCI05117cBgsl-3NqkMwp4x63pFlF/view?usp=sharing) html files and put them in the same directory as the example shiny app code below.

**Example:**

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    navbarPage("ShinyExample",
        
        tabPanel("TEST", HTML("FirstPage"), includeHTML("test.html")),
        
        tabPanel("TEST2", HTML("SecondPage"), includeHTML("NetworkAnimation.html"))
  
    )

)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

    # Stuff to render and save the network Animation happens here

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Expected Behavior:**

`test.html` and `NetworkAnimation.html` should only be rendered within their respective `tabPanel()`

**Observed Behavior:**

`test.html` is only rendered in it's respective tabPanel() but `NetworkAnimation.html` is rendered on both `tabPanel()` s

Answer (score 3):

The network-widget is appended to the body in the `NetworkAnimation.html`-Javascript:
`target = d3.select('body').append('div').style({width: '100%', height: '100%'}).node();`.

If you want it to be on Tab 2 only, you can include a div with id and change the JavaScript line, so that it gets appended to your div.

My App looks like this:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  ## Include shinyjs
  useShinyjs(),
  ## Set ID of navbarPage
  navbarPage("ShinyExample", id = "navid",
             tabPanel("TEST", includeHTML("test.html")),
             tabPanel("TEST2",
                      ## Include new DIV here & Set initial height
                      div(id="appendhere", style="height: 1090px;"), 
                      includeHTML("NetworkAnimation.html"))
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
    observe({
        req(input$navid == "TEST2")
        runjs('$("#appendhere").resize()')
    })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

and the JS is changed to

```
target = d3.select('#appendhere').append('div').style({width: '100%', height: '100%'}).node();
```

I also had to include `shinyjs`, to run some JavaScript when TAB2 is active. The width/height of the svg is calculated when it is rendered and therefore initially 0 (or actually -60).
If you remove the `runjs` line, you will see that the network is not visible.

By changing the browser size, the network gets redrawn and width/height are updated. Therefore we call `$("#appendhere").resize()` when TAB2 is active.

There is still the following error in the browser console, but everything seems to work fine.

> Uncaught TypeError: a is undefined

Comment: Thanks! This works fine with the existing network object. The issue is though, that the network object is not static but is recreated for every new datafile that is uploaded. Is there a way to automatically do the necessary changes in the .html file as part of the script?

Comment: Could you clarify the second sentence? How do you upload new datafiles? The current graph-data is static inside the HTML or?

Comment: Yes, sorry, that was unclear. In my shiny app, users have the ability to upload their own data. The serverlogic then uses this dataset to create the html animation file for the network structure and displays it to the user. So the html file is not a static file that I can just put on the server but something that is generated by the server when the user uploads data.